# Nodejs how to listen for keyboard input after server starts

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a scripts that launches a node server:

```js
// server.js
const server = http.createServer(...);

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Server Started on Port ${port}`);
});
```

Another script that executes the server:

```js
// start.js
const { fork } = require('child_process');

const worker = fork('./server.js');
```

I start like this:

```
$ node start.js
```

While the server is on, when the user writes `rs` + `Enter` in the terminal, I would like to restart the server(edit: what I mean by restart is kill the process + respawn). It should be done ideally in `start.js`

Of course I could directly run `server.js` but I'm doing other bootstrap stuffs in `start.js`.

I tried to pass `silent: true` to the fork options, and:

```js
worker.stdin.on('data', data => console.log(data));
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Why are you using a child process? Start your server with `node server.js`.

Comment: Do you know how to listen for keyboard input in nodejs in general?

Comment: @Bergi I do other bootstrap stuff in ```start.js```. I know it's with ```process.stdin```, but I can't make it work. I've been searching for days so this question I a simple summary of what I want to achieve.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? It's much easier to help if we can see what you did right

Comment: So "restarting the server" means killing the subprocess and spawning another?

Comment: @Bergi yes kill and spawning the worker is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found, just needed to pipe the process stdout